# Netty Channel.write from another string do not work

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

```
private void handleWebSocketFrame(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) {

    // Check for closing frame
    if (frame instanceof CloseWebSocketFrame) {
        handshaker.close(ctx.channel(), (CloseWebSocketFrame) frame.retain());
        return;
    }
    if (frame instanceof PingWebSocketFrame) {
        ctx.channel().write(new PongWebSocketFrame(frame.content().retain()));
        return;
    }
    if (!(frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame)) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("%s frame types not supported", frame.getClass()
                .getName()));
    }

    // Send the uppercase string back.
    String request = ((TextWebSocketFrame) frame).text();
    if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
        logger.fine(String.format("%s received %s", ctx.channel(), request));
    }
    Message msg = new Message(ctx.channel(), request);
    ReadQueueHandler.getInstance().addMessageToProcess(msg);
}




public class ReadQueueHandler implements Runnable {
private static int POOL_SIZE = 3;
private static ReadQueueHandler instance;

private final BlockingQueue<Message> messageQueue;
private final ExecutorService threadPool;
private final int threadPoolSize;
private final boolean isActive;

private ReadQueueHandler() {
    this.threadPoolSize = POOL_SIZE;
    this.threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    this.messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Message>();
    isActive = true;
    initThreadPool();
}

private void initThreadPool() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.threadPoolSize; i++) {
        this.threadPool.execute(this);
    }
}

/**
 * Add message to read queue
 * 
 * @param message
 *            - adding message
 */
public void addMessageToProcess(Message message) {
    if (message != null) {
        this.messageQueue.add(message);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isActive) {
        Message message = null;
        try {
            message = this.messageQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exceptio " + e);
            /*
             * TODO Add logging
             */
        }
        if (message != null) {
            Channel channel = message.getChannel();
            channel.write(new TextWebSocketFrame("Message handled "));
        }

    }
}

public static ReadQueueHandler getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ReadQueueHandler();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

If i execute Channel.write("something") instead of adding data to queue, then all work fine and client get data. But if Channel.write("") execute from another thread, than data is not got. What can be reason? Channel write can not be execute from another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems like you forgot to call flush() after the write is done to guaranteer it's flushed to the socket. For example you could fix this by use:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("Message handled "));
```